# Minimum SDK to be used for setting up actionbarsherlock in android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to use Actionbarsherlock in my application, which version of Android SDK is required to setup for it?
Can you please provide me real time examples which uses Actionbarsherlock, also please provide me some sample example links which shows how to implement Actionbarsherlock in simple android application

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the documentation at
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Since the library is an extension of the compatibility libraries, I believe you can set android:minSdkVersion to 4.

I always use the latest SDK (4.x) regardless of what version I target for my app. You question is a bit vague. When you get started, or run into problems I suggest you ask more specific questions.

Comment: Glenn, i have android 2.2 SDK installed in my machine, i m unable to import the actionbarsherlock lib... :( kindly suggest me